# How to assign getFieldValues("Custom.RevisionCount", returnOriginalValue) to a variable in VSTS custom Extension html file?

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I am very new to Javascript and VSTS extension creation.I am looking to create an extension calculate the revision count of a Work Item in VSTS. For this I am trying with sample java script in Work Item form extension.In the java script I am not able get the current value of the revision count, and assign it variable to make increment for each state transition.

From VSTS I found this method to get the field value, but How to implement it 
`getFieldValues("Custom.RevisionCount", returnOriginalValue);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Work item form page sample</title>
</head>

<body style="overflow:auto;">
    <script src="node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
            usePlatformScripts: true,
            //usePlatformStyles: true
        });

        //VSS.ready(function () {

        VSS.require(["TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services"], function (_WorkItemServices) {
               // VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/Core/RestClient"], function(VSS_Service, Tfs_Core_WebApi) {
                //        var client = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(Tfs_Core_WebApi.CoreHttpClient4);

            // Get the WorkItemFormService.  This service allows you to get/set fields/links on the 'active' work item (the work item
            // that currently is displayed in the UI).
            function getWorkItemFormService()
            {
                return _WorkItemServices.WorkItemFormService.getService();
            }

            var project=VSS.getWebContext().project.name;
            var teamid=VSS.getWebContext().team.id;
            // Register a listener for the work item page contribution
            VSS.register(VSS.getContribution().id, function () {
                return {
                    // Called when the active work item is modified
                    onFieldChanged: function(args) {

                    if(project=="TFS_Training")
                    {                                               
                                //alert(args);                                                     
                                var data=JSON.stringify(args);
                                var a2=JSON.parse(data);
                                var a3 = a2["changedFields"];

                               //var i = getFieldValues("Custom.RevisionCount", returnOriginalValue);
                                getWorkItemFormService().then(function(service)

                               //{            
                                 // Get the current values for a few of the common fields
                                 //   service.getFieldValues("Custom.RevisionCount").then(
                                 //     function (value) {
                                 //       $(".events").append($("<div/>").text("onLoaded - " + JSON.stringify(value)));
                                 // });

                               var i = 0

                                if(a3.hasOwnProperty("System.State"))
                                {
                                    function myFunction(i) {
                                        return i+1;
                                    }

                                    getWorkItemFormService().then(function (service)
                                    {
                                        {
                                        //service.setFieldValue("System.Title", "Requirment changed");
                                        service.setFieldValue("Custom.RevisionCount", myFunction(i));
                                        }

                                        // errorMessage="statechanged";   
                                        // service.setError(errorMessage);
                                        });   
                                }                             
                    }
                    },
                }
            });

            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
         });
        //});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Still showing value 1 for each state transition

Comment: Not sure if totally get your point. Seems you want to fetch a value from customized field. And then increase one of the value. Then assign it back to this field. However, according to your shared code, you just `var i=0`, every time you run your code it will return 0+1, that maybe why it always show value 1 for each state transition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes, In that variable 'i' i need to put current value the custom field for every time. So, How to write method for that, Can you please provide the sample code for that.is this process is works var i = getFieldValues("Custom.RevisionCount", returnOriginalValue); to assign the current value of that field to varible "i"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define i, you could directly use value in the setFieldValue. After you fetch the value from workitem service. Kind of this (not familiar with js part),change your code based on your needs：

```
getWorkItemFormService().then(function(service)

                            {   // get work item service first

                function getWorkItemFormService()
                           {
                            return _WorkItemServices.WorkItemFormService.getService();
                           }


                             // Get the current values for a few of the common fields
                             //   get filed value here then use below function
                                 function (value) {
                             //       $(".events").append($("<div/>").text("onLoaded - " + JSON.stringify(value)));


                                    //service.setFieldValue("System.Title", "Requirment changed");
                                    service.setFieldValue("Custom.RevisionCount", value+1;)
                                    }                                      
                            }
```

More details please refer this official tutorial here: [setFieldValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/services/workitemformservice?view=azure-devops#setfieldvalue)